# How we can upload multiple images on cloudinairy in slots with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-3.1, cloudinary

My requirement is to upload multiple images on cloud in slots.
For example i have 100 images in array then images goes in 3 - 3 slots on cloudinairy and and at the time of upload i have any error like time out then it handle exception and goes to upload next image of same slot and this process continue until all images will uploaded.

Comment: Can you explain what do you mean by 3-3 slots on Cloudinary?
Also, what's the error message you receive on upload?

Comment: Some time i am getting Time Out Error and when i get this error my server is stuck so i want to handle this and also my server should not stuck.